# Short description of products not showing at shop page(archive-product.php)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to figure out how I can display the short description for each product at the shop page(archive-product.php).

Here in this screenshot you can see i have placed a dummy text at the short description field.

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/excerpt_zpse08fd1d6.jpg

But it doesn't reflect on the shop page. It only shows the product price, rating and also add to cart button

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/description_zps916077d0.jpg.

I have already copied the woocommerce templates files and placed them at woocommerce folder in the root of my theme

UPDATE:

```
 //ADD SHORT DESCRIPTION SHOP PAGE
if ( ! function_exists( 'add_product_description' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_price() {
            wc_get_template( 'single-product/short-description.php' );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item action hook. In woocommerce you can define your own function which will trigger and add the description to your product. To achieve this ,use

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_product_description');

if ( ! function_exists( 'add_product_description' ) ) {
    function add_product_description() {
            wc_get_template( 'loop/product_description_snippet.php' );
    }
}
```

Create a file product_description_snippet.php(inside the theme/woocommerce/loop) ,where you can add code to grab product description.

Comment: I had to edit the code the you gave to since it was not working properly. After implementing the code on my functions.php. The short description replaced the price.

Comment: The code is to give you the idea what need to be done, to get the description. Let me know if you still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but I'm going to post the solution I found thanks to @M.P. Korstanje answer.

Insted of using woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook, just use woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook and echo the excerpt. All hooks in the shop page can be found [here](http://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/)

The code is then like that:

```html
/*
* Add product short description to the shop page
*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_product_description');

if ( ! function_exists( 'add_product_description' ) ) {
    function add_product_description() {
            the_excerpt();
    }
}
```